# PC logs off instead of shuts down

Tags: 11.10, shutdown

I’ve upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10 but I have a problem with shutdown. When I turn off my PC it do the logout instead the shutdwon. When arrive to violet screen (login) than I can shutdown my Pc and all is ok.

Comment: I had the same issue on both PC + laptop and no report or fix for this bug

Answer (score 2):

I managed to add an extended menu somehow Probably by following [this guide](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/things-to-tweak-after-installing-ubuntu.html)
but feel free to report it as a bug to ubuntu if you think it is a usability issue. I think the correct category would be [indicator-me](https://launchpad.net/indicator-me)

Answer (score 0):

When this happens to me it is because I have logged into another virtual terminal on the computer and not logged out there. I've always assumed that Ubuntu was stopping me from aborting what that "other" user was doing in their session.

When I ask for a shutdown from the last remaining session it does shutdown for me.

Sometimes I'll just type `sudo shutdown -h now` and not worry about it. Ubuntu will shutdown right away no matter what.